# How to safely escape data that contains HTML attributes

Tags: escaping

I am not looking for [esc_attr()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/), which escapes data to be used within attributes.

I am looking for a function that outputs one or more HTML attributes within an HTML tag.

For example:

```
<div <?php echo escape_me('class="whatever"'); ?> >hey</div>
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [wp_kses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)

You could use `wp_kses` to define specific html-tag/attribute combinations to be permitted in the escaped output.

```
$allowed_html = [
  'div' => [
    'class' => [],
  ],
];

echo wp_kses( '<div class="whatever">hey</div>', $allowed_html );
```

#### [wp_kses_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/)

You could use `wp_kses_post`. It's a pretty heavy function to use for such a purpose, but it is a valid way to escape your output.

```
<div <?php echo wp_kses_post('class="whatever"'); ?> >hey</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will wait to see if someone knows a more simple solution before marking this as the correct answer. I am just trying to follow WP Coding Standards and I am forced to escape all output, even if I know I can trust the output (because it's actually coming from hardcoded switch cases).